# Split Excel sheet into multiple sheets

Tags: excel-2010

I would like to break an Excel Sheet into multiple sheets

For Example:

Lets say there is a sheet with 7 columns as shown below

Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7

I would like to break it into 3 sheets like shown below, Column1 would be common in all sheets.

Column1, Column2, Column3 -- Sheet 1

Column1, Column4, Column5 -- Sheet 2

Column1, Column6, Column7 -- Sheet 3

Is this possible? I had been searching the internet for a solution for almost a day now, but I have not got any related solution.

Comment: It is possible if you use (for example) VBA. Do you know any programming language?

Comment: No. I don't know any programming language. I wanted to import the Excel file( actual file has 3000 columns ) into SQL Server. I wanted to break the sheet into sheets of 250 columns with 1 common column which can then be handled by SQL Server programming.

Comment: In that case - why don't you import the file to a temp table (BULK INSERT) and run the split queries from there?

Answer (score 0):

This will DO what you WANT:

```
Sub DataToDiffSheets()
Dim count As Long

    count = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

    Range("A1:A" & CStr(count)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D1:E" & CStr(count)).Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("B1:C" & CStr(count)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("F1:G" & CStr(count)).Cut
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("B1:C" & CStr(count)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

It's not the best and it's not the cleanest, but it'll work.